# Angular app base url not getting append with static resources

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular10

I have angular v10 application.Before i was using without `APP_BASE_HREF` provider.
Now i have added `APP_BASE_HREF` in AppModule `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/myapp'}`.

Which all static resources are using in application for those base href is not getting appended as prefix in resouces.

**for example**

```
dist/resources/images/Car.png
```

Using in application some where like

```html
<img src="dist/resources/images/Car.png"/>
```

And in `Network Request URL` also it's showing without basehref

```
http://localhost:9040/dist/resources/images/Car.png
```

but i want with base href like

```
http://localhost:9040/myapp/dist/resources/images/Car.png
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>myapp</title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app></app>
    </body>
</html>
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```json
    {
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "es2020",
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
          "es2017",
          "dom"
        ],
        "paths": {
          "myapp": [
            "dist/resources/*"
          ]
        },
        "resolveJsonModule": true
      }
    }
```

**project structure**

```
dist
       -resources
          -images
              -Car.png
ClientApp
       -app
           -components
           -app.module.ts 
       -appResourcesFiles
            -images
               -Car.png
            -js
            -css
```

Is there any configuration missing for baseHref? How to get resources request with baseHref?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you mapping from dist..? That is not exactly normal..?

Comment: @MikeOne what is the other way  i can use that ..could you suggest?

Comment: After a build you usually have a dist/appName folder..? Do you also have a dist folder in your src maybe..?

Comment: yes that modified and current app structure is like `src`,`dist ` both are parallel folder and on application build generating resouces under `dist/` folder from src resources...like updated  in question

Answer (score 0):

Add path in paths array of tsconfig.json and give a name like myApp

```
"paths": {
      "myApp": [
        "dist/resources/*"
      ],
    }
```

Comment: it's not working..i have added in `tsconfig.base.json`